# External payment method API - Deal with callback security

Tags: rest, security, stripe-payments, owasp, java-security

Many Payment Method providers API like [Braintree](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/webhooks/create/java), [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices), etc etc provide a callback system that allow the merchant to be notified with the result of transaction.

The main question is: How I can be safe from malevolent requests?

Suppose an attacker can reproduce our exposed callback REST API (obviously with HTTPS) this would lead in many fake successful transactions.

Is there any method to prevent this? I read about CRSF token on Stripe link, however it's unclear to me how it would be securely passed between my ecommerce site and provider API.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe's callback system is called webhooks (https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)
To prevent potential attacks, Stripe will send the callback content together with a signature. The signature is a (HAMC SHA256) hash of the callback content with timestamp and webhook secret. You could verify the signature (https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures) to ensure that the data is indeed sent from Stripe.

Comment: Thanks: This applies to Stripe, but generically speaking is there any way to prevent malevolus calls?

Comment: Yes, you are right that is the Stripe way to prevent potential man-in-the-middle attack or replay attack. 
But it does rely on the third party system to implement in the first place. 

To proactively protecting your system, what you could do is probably whitelist domains where your callback handle will entertain. E.g. for stripe, you could just whitelist any callback from *.stripe.com and reject other requests